# Does “nor” replace “not even”?

Tags: negation

I have recently learned to use *nor* in sentences and according to me, as I personally evaluated, *nor* replaces *not even* in many situations. For example:

> He does not like studying, **nor** does he bring good marks.

Now I believe that the above sentence can be reframed as:

> He does not like studying, **not even** does he bring good marks.

Is my interpretation correct, or I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is not idiomatic English. A native speaker would say "He doesn't like studying; he doesn't even get good marks."

The sense of *nor* would be "He doesn't get good marks either."

The sentence doesn't make much sense with *not even*, because it implies that the subject would be expected to get good marks even though he doesn't enjoy studying.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The sentence of *nor* is grammatically correct, right?

Comment: Yes, though it would be more idiomatic to say 'get good marks'.